# Repositioning parallax background-position

Tags: html, css, background, parallax, background-position

On the right side of my site, I have parallax scrolling images so I'm trying to reposition the .image-greet element so that when you are at the top of the website, the bottom of the rose [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8xTF.jpg) is centered and fills up the window pane.

Currently, only the top of the image brick wall is showing. I'm having difficulties modifying the background-position so that it moves up the image.

I tried using different variations of background-position, background-position-x, background-position-y, and changing offsets but I've struggled to get it right.

Here is the complete code in action:
https://jsfiddle.net/38wu4dcs/7/

```
.image-greet,
.image-greet.load {
  
  grid-column: images;
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8xTF.jpg");
  margin: 6% auto;
  width: 75%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: white;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 55%;

  background-size: 40% auto;
  background-position: 90% 20%;
}
```

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Where does the blue splash panel come into this?

Comment: @RichardHunter You can disregard the blue background on the left side. I only made it a different color to show the site was cut in half

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out through this resource: https://css-tricks.com/positioning-offset-background-images/

"If you need to position a background-image in CSS 20px from the left and 10px from the top, that’s easy. You can do background-position: 20px 10px;. But what if you wanted to position it 20px from the right and 10px from the bottom?"

So I applied it and did

background-position: right 25px bottom 250px;